# How check time overlaps in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I created a model: **Lecture(start_time, end_time, location)**. I want to write validation functions to check wether the new lecture's time overlapping with saved lectures in database. So that I can find out if the location is occupied in that time. My function is:

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :title, :position, presence: true

validates :start_time, :end_time, format: { with: /([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])/,
         message: "Incorrect time format" }

validate: time_overlap

def time_overlap
    Lecture.all.each do |user| 
       if (user.start_time - end_time) * (start_time - user.end_time) >= 0                       
       errors.add(:Base, "time overlaps")
       end
     end 
end

end
```

The error message: *NoMethodError in LecturesController#create
undefined method `-@' for nil:NilClass*. How to write this function in right format?

Comment: You mentioned you are getting error in you controller and still haven't added the controller code??

Comment: You have a typo in the `create` method of your `lectures_controller.rb` (which, incidentally, you neglected to post). Leaving that aside, your approach to time conflicts is inefficient. Rather than loading up all lectures from the database and comparing them in Ruby, you're better off constructing a query that selects lectures with start_time < new_lecture.start_time and  end_time > new_lecture.end_time. Don't do in application code what your database can do for you.

Comment: The controller works fine without time_overlap function, I just do not understand what ''undefined method `-@' for nil:NilClass" in this occasion. I guess my code in time_overlap has wrong ruby style. Hope to know how to check whether time overlaps with correct code.

Comment: `-@` is a method: try typing `1.send(:-@)`. It represents negation.  Now try typing `nil.send(:-@)`. Somewhere you have a nil value, probably a start_time or end_time, that is trying to be negated. Try also typing `Time.zone.now - nil`. This should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @runchu I would second the recommendation to move the filtering into the db, especially since this runs for every save of the lecture object. You could also validate this way only on create or when the start or end times change. In any case, though, @MarsAtomic you're right on efficiency but your query does not include all possible overlapping lectures. I'd use the logic already written to put in the query: `Lecture.where("(lectures.start_time - ?) * (? - lectures.end_time) >= 0", self.end_time, self.start_time).present?`

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz I think you'll find if you use >= you'll find that the result set produces inaccurate results in "human terms." A scheduled event that ends at 17:00 would count as a conflict with a second event that starts at 17:00, but people don't normally think of such an occurrence as a conflict. Adding equality would force events to start at least one ms later to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ruby 2.3.0's Time class: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html

You can use it to check if a Time instance is before or after another Time instance, such as:

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = Time.now
t1 < t2
=> true
t1 > t2
=> false
```

So, to check if a given time would exist during an existing Lecture in the database, you could write some Ruby to check if the proposed Lecture's start time or finish time sits after the start time AND before the end time of any existing Lectures.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while `<` is usually good enough, you also need to validate the "presence" of both values before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two slots of time, as:

```
start_time_a
end_time_a
start_time_b
end_time_b
```

There are three possible cases where there can be an overlap between the two time slots.

1) `start_time_b >= start_time_a && start_time_b =< end_time_a` ( i.e, slot b starts somewhere in the middle of slot a )
2) `end_time_b >= start_time_a && end_time_b <= end_time_a` ( i.e, slot b ends somewhere between slot a )
3) `start_time_b <= start_time_a && end_time_b >= end_time_a` ( i.e, slot b is larger than slot a, and completely covers it.

If you check for these three conditions, you can determine if there's an overlap between two time slots.

Conditions 1 & 2 can be simplified using `start_time_b.between?(start_time_a, end_time_a)`.